# Android/Java. Как отобразить активити в форме Диалога?

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity, style, dialogfragment

Необходимо отобразить активити в форме Диалога.. чтобы задний фон расплывчат был.. А у самой активити должны быть скругленные углы.

Вот как на рисунке:

[image: Рис1]

Как это делается? Что и В каких методах или файлах прописывать?

Comment: Есть библиотека реализующая данную задачу https://github.com/tvbarthel/BlurDialogFragment

Answer (score 2):

В манифесте пропиши у активити:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

Или просто сделай прозрачный фон, а на самой активити рисуй что хочешь.

Для этого в манифесте пропиши:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Создай layout для диалог-фрагмента.
public class AddList extends DialogFragment implements 
Далее тебе нужно будет создать такой класс:

```
public class <NameOfDialog> extends DialogFragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.<your_layout>, container);
        adb.setView(rootView);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

И внутри прописать всё, что нужно.
А внутри нужного активити прописать:

```
<NameOfDialog> dialog = new <NameOfDialog>();
dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "<Message about open dialog>");
```